# MS Access too many client tasks

Tags: ms-access, client-server

I was getting this error earlier today on my phone when I was trying to access a website I have been developing over the past year or so. I wasn't able to save the exact error message, but it wasn't returning any query results and would give me an error stating there were 'too many client tasks'.

Google searching doesn't help much to resolve the issue... am I supposed to be closing client connections to my database? I thought Access did that on it's own. There's no way there are ever more than 4-5 people on the site at once, so I'm not sure what would be causing this.

I do have one sneaking suspicion... there is an auto sign out and close the tab after 10 minutes feature for the site. Code looks like this:

```
var idleTime = 0;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
                var idleInterval = setInterval('timerIncrement()', 60000); // 1 minute

                //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
                $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
                    idleTime = 0;
                });
                $(this).keypress(function (e) {
                    idleTime = 0;
                });
            })
            function timerIncrement() {
                idleTime = idleTime + 1;
                if (idleTime > 9) { // 10 minutes
                    document.getElementById('logoutbutton').click();
                    window.open('', '_self', ''); //bug fix
                    window.close();
                }
            }";
```

Could this be the culprit?

Any help would be great. I'm drawing a blank on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access is a desktop database and not well suited as a web-oriented database. (Many would state that it is a very poor choice.)

Anyway, a quick Google reveals [this page](http://www.aspmine.com/asp/errors/too-many-client-task) which suggests that you need to explicitly close the database connection, and release any resources, as soon as you can. The page refers to ASP but you haven't told use which server-side technology you are using - but the same principle applies regardless.

Many, more web-capable, databases, such as MySQL, will implicitly close connections, and release resources, when no longer needed - or when the (server-side) script ends.